# How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(n+j)}=\frac{1}{(k-2)!(k-1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to prove that for any $k\geq 2$ we have: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(n+j)}=\frac{1}{(k-2)!(k-1)^2}=\frac{1}{(k-1)\cdot(k-1)!},$$
but I don't have an idea about how to deal with the $\prod$ in the LHS.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

\begin{align}\frac1{(n+1)\cdots(n+k)}\\&=\frac1{k-1}\frac{(n+k)-(n+1)}{(n+1)\cdots(n+k)}\\&=\frac1{k-1}\left(\frac1{(n+1)\cdots(n+k-1)}-\frac1{(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}\right)\\&=\frac1{k-1}(v_n-v_{n+1})\end{align}
so by telescoping the given sum is
$$\frac1{k-1}(v_0-\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n)=\frac1{(k-2)!(k-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

If we set:
$$A_k \triangleq \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}$$
it follows that, for any $k\geq 2$:
$$ \color{red}{A_k} - k A_{k+1} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!(n+1)}{(n+k+1)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+k+1)!} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!} = \color{red}{A_k}-\frac{1}{k!}$$
so we have:

> $$ A_{k+1}=\frac{1}{k\cdot k!}$$

as wanted, for any $k\geq 2$. Then we just need to prove $A_2=1$, that easily follows from the telescopic property:
$$ A_2 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right) = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\ {1 \over \prod_{j\ =\ 1}^{k}\,\pars{n + j}}
     ={1 \over \pars{k - 2}!\,\pars{k - 1}^{2}}
     ={1 \over \pars{k - 1}\,\pars{k - 1}!}:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\ {1 \over \prod_{j\ =\ 1}^{k}\,\pars{n + j}}}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\ {n! \over \pars{n + k}!}
={1 \over \pars{k - 1}!}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{k} \over \Gamma\pars{n + k + 1}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over \pars{k - 1}!}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t}^{k - 1}\,\dd t
={1 \over \pars{k - 1}!}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{k - 1}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}t^{n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={1 \over \pars{k - 1}!}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{k - 1}\,{1 \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over \pars{k - 1}\,\pars{k - 1}!}}
={1 \over \pars{k - 1}\,\pars{k - 1}\,\pars{k - 2}!}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over \pars{k - 2}!\,\pars{k - 1}^{2}}}
\end{align}